# Generate variable according to distribution exp(x)/(exp(1)-1)

Tags: r, random-generation

I need to generate variable from the distribution $\ e^x \over e-1$ from 0 to 1 only using uniform variables.

The idea I'm following is the Inverse Transforming. I get the inverse cdf function and apply the uniform variable on it, so:

The cdf is the same as the original distribution.

The inverse is: $\ ln(x(e-1)) $

But this function is < 0  for x in [0,1], so it is not the distribution of $\ e^x \over e-1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function $e^x/(e-1)$ is not a cdf, or at least there is something missing from your description!

Comment: I'm using the cdf integrating $\ e^x \over e-1$ which is $\ e^x \over e-1$

Comment: please tag self study

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X\leq t) = \int_0^t f(u)dt$, where $f$ is the density for your r.v. $X$ ....

Comment: The integral $\int_0^t e^u/(e-1) du$ is very much not $e^t/(e-1)$.  How do I know that without doing anything (even pretending I don't know the answer)?   They don't agree at $t=0$..

Comment: Ohhh I get it now. When x = 0, the integral value is $\ 1 \over (e-1) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You integrated the PDF incorrectly and thus your CDF is wrong- it should be $F(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{e - 1}$, which has inverse $g(y) = \ln(1 + (e-1)y))$, which is positive for $y \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse that you're using must be of the CDF, not PDF.

Knuth in Vol2 of TAOCP has a ton methods to generate randoms if you're interested.

Comment: I'm using the cdf integrating $\ e^x \over e-1$ which is $\ e^x \over e-1$